# how can I get categories that share at least one product with another given category?

Tags: mysql

how can i get categories that share at least one product with another given category in sql?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `p2c`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `p2c`;
CREATE TABLE `p2c` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`,`categories_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of p2c
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1001', '1');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1001', '2');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1002', '1');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1003', '2');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1004', '1');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1004', '2');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1005', '3');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1006', '2');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1006', '3');
INSERT INTO `p2c` VALUES ('1007', '4');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that :

You make an inner join on same table. The products_id must be identical, and categories_id must be different.

```
select distinct p2.categories_id
from p2c p1
inner join p2c p2 
    on p1.products_id = p2.products_id and 
       p1.categories_id <> p2.categories_id
where p1.categories_id = 1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef05c/10)

Answer (score 3):

```
 select distinct a.categories_id as categories_associated_with_1
    from p2c as a
    inner join (select products_id
    from p2c
    where categories_id=1) as b
    on a.products_id=b.products_id
where a.categories_id<>1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT categories_id
  FROM p2c
  WHERE
    categories_id != 1
    AND products_id IN
      (SELECT products_id FROM p2c WHERE categories_id = 1)
```

try out in [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47538/19).